# How do I create a PopupMenuButton in flutter where the dropdown with children should come at the top of the actual menu?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I want the PopUpMenu should be opened the way how it is showed in the design

[How it should supposed to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGv3M.png)

Actually I tried giving an offset by I couldn't manage it with length of the children and the device size as well, either it is getting too much padding at the bottom or it is just coming over the popupmenu itself and I've searched in the internet, I couldn't find any solution for this exact case

Answer (score 0):

**I am using this package https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_button2**

```
final List<String> items = [
  'Item1',
  'Item2',
  'Item3',
  'Item4',
];
String? selectedValue;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
        child: DropdownButton2(
          hint: Text(
            'Select Item',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 14,
              color: Theme.of(context).hintColor,
            ),
          ),
          items: items
                  .map((item) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
            value: item,
            child: Text(
              item,
              style: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 14,
              ),
            ),
          ))
                  .toList(),
          value: selectedValue,
          onChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
              selectedValue = value as String;
            });
          },
          buttonStyleData: const ButtonStyleData(
            height: 40,
            width: 140,
          ),
          menuItemStyleData: const MenuItemStyleData(
            height: 40,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but this package also takes the offset only under the DropdownStyleData class, I want something like a position field, where the PopupMenuButton has a property called position but it only has PopupMenuPosition.under and PopupMenuPosition.over only, not PopupMenuPosition.above how can I customize it?

Comment: offset Changes the position of the dropdown menu

Comment: Is there any other to achieve the same thing without using the offset?

Comment: you can position the PopupMenuButton using a Positioned widget within a Stack